# c3js custom title on hover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Need help for C3.js donut chart to display custom title on hover, below is my code snippet to do that:

```
function LegislationWiseOP(Table) {
        //var mData = [], mItem = [], mMinorIdData = [], mMinorIdItem = [], mTotalCnt = 0;//COmmented by Nadeem on 06Oct17
        var mData = [], mItem = [], mMinorIdData = [], mMinorIdItem = [], mTotalCnt = 0, mMinorNameFull = [];//Added by Nadeem on 06Oct17


        if (Table[0] == null)//Added by Nadeem on 29May17
            mTotalCnt = 0;
        else
            mTotalCnt = Table[0].TotCnt;

        $('#LegWiseOpenProcTotal').text(mTotalCnt);


        for (var i = 0; i < Table.length; i++) {
            mItem = [], mMinorIdItem = [];

            mItem.push(Table[i].MinorName, Table[i].Perc);
            mData.push(mItem);
            //alert(Table[i].MinorNameFull);
            mMinorNameFull.push(Table[i].MinorNameFull);//Added by Nadeem on 06Oct17

            mMinorIdItem.push(id = Table[i].MinorName, value = Table[i].MinorId);

            mMinorIdData.push(mMinorIdItem);
        }

        var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart2',
            data: {
                columns: mData,
                type: 'donut',
                onclick: function (d, i) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < mMinorIdData.length; i++) {
                        if (mMinorIdData[i][0] == d.id)
                            openRadWindow("LegWisePenProc", "", mMinorIdData[i][1], "", mMinorIdData[i][0], "");
                    }
                },
            },
            color: {
                pattern: ['#336799', '#01A3AE', '#80D1D5', '#FEE506', '#2C973D']
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
            },
            donut: {
                title: ""
            },tooltip: {
                format: {
                    title:
                        function (d, i) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < mMinorNameFull.length; i++) {
                                return mMinorNameFull[i];
                            }
                            //function (d) { return alert(d); 'Data ' + mMinorNameFull[d]; }
                        }
                }
            }


});
        }
```

I tried this also --> [tried this](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/645) 
please guide me if anything I missed,
My main requirement is display short name on donut chart and on hover title display full length text which is present in mMinorNameFull array.

Comment: request your help urgently...

Comment: I have tried with below code, but result is giving all the minor name as same time instead of 1 by 1 on hover of that donut area: , tooltip: {
                    format: {
                        title:
                                    //function (d) { return 'Data ' + d; }
                    function (d) {
                        return mMinorNameFull;
                        //for (var i = 0; i < mMinorNameFull.length; i++) {
                        //    return mMinorNameFull[i];
                        //}
                    }
                    }
                }

Comment: request for help, as still struggling with the same issue, I am surprised with the response on SO took too long but no one have replied yet, request every one to help

Comment: You can check my post.. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

It has been very late but for others it would be helpful. You can use `tooltip` like this:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
                data: {
                    // data configurations
                },
                donut: {
                    // donut configurations
                },
                tooltip: {
                    format: {
                        value: function (value, ratio, id) {
                            return value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```